# Using ELKI how would I implement a distance function that is dependent on the amount of clusters?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, computer-science, elki

How could I implement a distance function that is dependent on the amount of clusters?

I've been looking at the documentation and it doesn't seem like I could implement a distance function for clustering that will take into account of those factors. I'm trying to implement spearman's rank order and coefficient, and burrow's delta.

Comment: Define "amount of clusters", and how you would use it. ELKI can support very complex distance functions. Both distances between clusters, set-based distances, and e.g. shared nearest neighbor distances.

Comment: @ErichSchubert for example Spearman's rank order coefficient is `r_{sc} = 1 - \frac{6}{n(n^2-1)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - y_i)^2` (latex) which relies on the knowledge of the amount of clusters meaning knowing what n is equal to.

Comment: `n` is the number of dimensions there, not the number of clusters. Spearman correlation (don't use that formula, it does not support ties!) can be used in ELKI by first normalizing your data via `IntegerRankTieNormalization`, then using `PearsonCorrelationDistanceFunction` (because Spearman is Pearson on the ranks). This is more efficient than implementing Spearman as a standalone distance function.

Comment: I read (but have not verified) that Burrow's delta is Standardization + Manhattan distance? Again, it will then be a lot faster to use this combination of filter+distance than to repeatedly standardize in the distance computations.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @benjrei it's hard to help you, if you do not answer...